# convert two-dimensional php array to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I have a two-dimensional php array, $phpar, in which both dimensions are indexed (0,1,2,...), and all values are plain text. Within a JavaScript function, I want to convert this array into a two-dimensional JavaScript array. I know the following code doesn't work, but it illustrates what I want to do.

```
jsfunction() {
    var jsarray = new Array();
    jsarray = <?php json_encode($phpar); ?>;
}
```

If the returned value is something other than a regular js array, like a JSON string, I need some help parsing that into what I want, please.

Comment: What you've done should work just fine, assuming `$phpar` really contains a two-dimensional array. (Except there's no need for the `= new Array()` part at all, you're just creating an array to throw it away on the next line). So what you want to do, if this isn't working, is look at what the *browser* receives for it, and update the PHP variable so it really contains a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Note that there is a possible security issue here: when $phpar depends on user-input, it might contain a string with a </script> tag, followed by malicious stuff to be injected in your web page.

Comment: Continued: adding the options JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS to json_encode would prevent this and some other vulnerabilities, but I wouldn't dare to say that this prevents all possible attacks. It's probably better to avoid inserting dynamic content in your JS scripts directly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe I'm just too tired for this today or something, but can you please explain why everyone's talking about `JSON.parse`? Is it me missing something, or is it plain hogwash? I'm just making sure I'm not the only one on this. O.o

Comment: @AardvarkSoup That's why you `json_encode` the stuff!!

Comment: @Christian: I'm sure I saw `JSON.parse` in the question. But it doesn't really matter, the question as it is now has the same result. **If** the PHP variable is a two-dimensional array, when it's output using `json_encode`, it should result in a two-dimensional JavaScript array (as JSON is a subset of JavaScript notation).

Comment: @Christian: Try including `json_encode('</script><script>alert("boo!");</script>')` into a JS script within an HTML page and you will be able to see why json_encode is not sufficient. The problem is that the HTML parser will assume your script ends with the </script> tag. Even if that tag is part of a Javascript string literal! When this is abused, the original script will now yield a Javascript parse error (because it ends in the middle of a string literal) and the attacker can inject any piece of Javascript that will be executed.

Comment: @AardvarkSoup That is absolutely **false**. Doing that yields the following string: `"<\/script><script>alert(\"boo!\");<\/script>"` There is no way this can be abused or executed as JS. See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/KT69M/ (the alert is to show the value of 's' and that the code indeed works).

Comment: @Christian: oops! I didn't know json_encode escaped the forward slash and apperantly made some silly mistake while (not very thorougly) testing in the PHP interpreter. My apologies, **I was completely wrong**. Please disregard my previous comments:P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure where your problem is...but the basic operation of `json_encode` simply looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsarray = <?php echo json_encode($phpar); ?>;

</script>
```

---

**Frankly, I don't see why the other people are suggesting throwing a javascript-compatible object/array into a string**, and worse the way they did it is **wrong**. If you want a JSON object string, this is the correct way of doing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsarray_string = <?php echo json_encode(json_encode($phpar)); ?>;
    //                                   ^           ^------ php array to js array
    //                                   '------------------ php string to js string
</script>
```

---

**By the way**, javascript objects can be accessed like arrays. Example:

```
var myArray = {1: 'hi', 2: 'bye'};
alert(myArray[2]); // this works!
```

The only difference is that myArray is not really a javascript array, eg, `myArray.constructor` is not `Array()`.

Comment: Got it, I'm with you now. This is a **comment**, not an answer. It's the same as my original comment: What the OP is doing should work. Until we have further information, it's impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying accomplish here in terms of you application's functionality?

PHP is a backend language and JavaScript is a frontend language. If you need the frontend to retrieve an object from the backend to use in your JavaScript you should use Ajax as opposed to putting PHP code inside your JavaScript.

Your Ajax method will call the relevant PHP method using an MVC-style URL ('/mycontroller/mymethod'). The PHP method should use use associative array(s) since JSON objects are key-value pairs. You should json_encode the array before returning it.

Here's some sample PHP code:

```
<?php #foo.php

public function bar() {
    $array = ('first-name' => 'John', 'last-name' => 'Doe');
    return json_encode($array);
}
```

On the frontend, your JSON object will consist of the same key value pairs as your associative array:

```
var getBar = function() {
    $.get('/foo/bar', function(data) {
        var string = 'My name is ' + data.first-name + ' ' + data.last-name';
        alert(string);
    }, json);
};
```

Comment: @Christian I deleted my original comments B/C I think we got a bit too personal To your point, there are some limited circumstances where it might make sense to have the backend populate an inline JSON object. To my points: 1. if one goes that route it's better to have the controller do the JSON encoding and print the object to a hidden div as opposed to using PHP inside of JS in the view; 2. Unobtrusive JS is usually better than inline or embedded JS B/C It's reusable, easier to maintain, and more performant. Finally, tight coupling impedes flexibility, scalability, and maintainability.Cheers

Comment: Cleaned up a bit myself. Must admit that my initial comment was probably too harsh. Your point is very valid, *but* one might as well have a JS view and output all these details registered throughout the system. Please also note that you've been hinting at MVC, which is only one pattern one might decide to work with. And finally, with this in mind, we don't know where the OP is going to use this code and frankly I leave this all up to him.

Comment: I agree 100%. Cheers sir!